# Create Microsoft Unified Service Desk Custom Layout

Tags: c#, unified-service-desk

So I have been trying to find a step by step guide for creating a custom layout for Microsoft Unified Service Desk V2.

I found this link but I really want to find something that gives me more information and explains how you deploy the custom layout etc.

Thanks!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn864920.aspx

Comment: This is much too open ended of a question. An answer could fill several pages. You need to narrow it down.